# Workaround for Chrome Driver not up to date with newest Chrome Release for Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the newest chrome update 121.0.6167.185 and the latest chrome driver is only 121.0.6167.85. I am using Selenium in a corporate environment, so I am behind a proxy so the driver manager doesn't work. I also can't downgrade chrome as that's managed by my company.

I've tried using different browsers (edge and firefox) and I run into the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run Chrome in headless mode ?

If not try like below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
driver = webdriver.chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get('your-url')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "Google Chrome for Testing" application, which has auto-update disabled. They are available on the dashboard [here](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/).

Use the links in the red rectangle.

[image]